# Serve assets from s3 bucket in Rails 4.2.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am just wondering if the configuration setup has changed at all (since Rails 4) with regards to setting up `asset_sync` and serving my assets from an s3 bucket.

I cannot seem to be able to serve my css or js assets (though images, jpg, png) are ok. I can upload everything to my s3 bucket.

I am trying to get this to work in my development environment before I push to production.

So my `asset_sync.rb` initializer is setup like so

```
if defined?(AssetSync)
  AssetSync.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'AWS'
    config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
    config.existing_remote_files = "delete"
    config.gzip_compression = true
    config.manifest = true
    config.custom_headers = { '.*' => { cache_control: 'max-age=315576000', expires: 1.year.from_now.httpdate } }
  end
end
```

So I know that this part is ok as assets are uploaded to the bucket, but when I try and render my page no css/js or image are shown. I have set this in my development.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

All I get back at the moment on each asset is a `403` forbidden error.

This is my IAM policy, maybe someone could spot something in here that isn't correct?

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    }
 ]
}
```

I have also added a bucket policy

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am looking for is for someone to show how they setup their Rails app with asset_sync please to see if I have missed anything.

Comment: That sounds more like a bucket policy or acl that is making all of the bucket content private.

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated the question with my bucket policy, would you alter that at all ?

Comment: Is that an s3 bucket policy or an iam policy (they are similar in syntax but quite different)

Comment: Thats an IAM policy, wasnt aware of the bucket policy as never had to do that before

Comment: looked into bucket policies aswell (thanks for the heads up) still getting 403 errors

Comment: If no bucket policy then it's probably the ACL on the individual files

Comment: would there be any reason why my images (jpg and png format) are being loaded but no my css or js ?